# Google Drive File ID and Folder ID conventions

Tags: google-drive-api

I am looking to get all files within a folder in Google Drive (given an initial folderId), including all files inside sub-folders. Currently, I am able to retrieve all files in a folder that does not contain any sub-folders, and I am trying to implement the next step of recursively looking through sub-folders and get'ing all the files within.

I'm using *drive.children.list* on a folderId, and receive an array of *drive#childReference* objects. Unfortunately, these objects don't directly tell me whether it is a folder or a document, but I've noticed that the folderIds are much shorter than the fileIds.

i.e. The first object below is a folder, and the second object is a file. The folder's id is much shorter than the file, but there is nothing else that helps me distinguish whether each object is a folder or a file.

```
[ { kind: 'drive#childReference',
       id: '0B2ecLLJU7rP3a2ZmVFZQVDdIRXM',
       selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B2ecLLJU7rP3YXM0U2tOVm1wcVE/children/0B2ecLLJU7rP3a2ZmVFZQVDdIRXM',
       childLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B2ecLLJU7rP3a2ZmVFZQVDdIRXM' },
     { kind: 'drive#childReference',
       id: '178rrwgIQxuoUgphvVYKppTM37PzT1yhzQOr9E1Shpf4',
       selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B2ecLLJU7rP3YXM0U2tOVm1wcVE/children/178rrwgIQxuoUgphvVYKppTM37PzT1yhzQOr9E1Shpf4',
       childLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/178rrwgIQxuoUgphvVYKppTM37PzT1yhzQOr9E1Shpf4' } ]
```

I'm really hoping that I don't have to make another request for each of the objects to determine whether it is a folder or a file. But I fear that simply determining the length of the ID is too weak. Does anyone have any suggestions? Would it be safe to make a determination based solely on the length of the id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder)

> A folder is a file with the MIME type application/vnd.google-apps.folder and with no extension.

So you can determine whether a `File` object is a folder by looking at it's `mimeType` key.

Answer (score 1):

**Would it be safe to make a determination based solely on the length of the id?**

no

**Does anyone have any suggestions?**

Some suggestions

- For each child ID, fetch its object. I think this is what you were trying to avoid doing.
- Instead of recursing the folders, do a files.list query for *all* folders, then iterate them to build an in-memory hierarchy.
- depending on your app, remember that files can have multiple parents. So a file in folder1/folder2/folder3 can have both folder3 *and* folder1 as parents. Then you simply need to query for all the children of folder1 to get all files.

Answer (score 0):

Make one call to [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).

Folder in Drive is considered as special type of file with metadata.
That makes it possible for you to fetch list of both file and folder using [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).
You can tell whether if the item is folder using `mimeType` which is returned as one of the fields of files resources.

By the way, it is highly recommended that you make api calls to explore user's folder on demand. API calls are slow and some heavy users might freeze your application. And you would easily hit API usage limit.